# jquery.min 500 internal error which code causes this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web

hi there i'm getting 500 internal server error when im pressing this button which does this :

```
$(".btn-email").on('click', function() {
    swal('Waiting','Please wait, sending email now','info');
    $.getJSON("/api/addvoter",{"email":$(".voter-email").val(),"vote_id":$(".vote-id").val()},function(result){
        if(result.success == 1){
            swal("Good job!", "Send an email to the voter successfully!", "success");
            $(".voter-email").val("");
        }else{
            sweetAlert("Oops...", result.content, "error");
        }
    });

});
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ZTp.png)

i'm using open-source blockvote's system which is [here](https://github.com/yfgeek/BlockVotes)

what could be causing this error?

Comment: Please see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)  documentation about 500 error. You need check error log from backend side.

Comment: The API is producing the error. Have you tried calling it from the browser or postman?

Comment: $.getJSON() method does an HTTP GET and not POST. You need to use $.post()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone will have same problem, the main issue was with database version itself and root url. it needs maria db and proper root url in apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The API is broken, fix it first

Comment: case is that API is working perfectly, adding / removing candidates & voters are based on API, and it only gives me error when i want to add voter  i'm getting error on main.js line 10 which is : $.getJSON("/api/addvoter",{"email":$(".voter-email").val(),"vote_id":$(".vote-id").val()},function(result){

Comment: Then have a look in the network panel (devtools) and check if the request is what you expect it to be.

Comment: i think you will be saving me lol i found thsi on network tools request on addvoter
: 
error: {type: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",…}
file: "/var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php"
line: 673
message: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'user_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `code` (`code`, `item_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (XDJJM12QW8DL6TJG, 1, , 2018-10-05 09:05:41, 2018-10-05 09:05:41))"
type: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"

have any idea what might fix it ? i guess

Comment: Parse the user_id to an integer. But I see the user_id value is empty. So that might be your problem, actually.